# CMake header dependency tracking doesn't seem to work with target_include_directories?

Tags: c++, cmake

With this extremely simple setup:

```
# CMakeLists.txt

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(foo)
add_executable(foo src/foo.cc include/foo.h)
target_include_directories(foo PRIVATE "include")
```

```cpp
// src/foo.cc

#include "foo.h"

int main() {}
```

```cpp
// include/foo.h

/* whatever */
```

I would expect cmake to recompile src/foo.cc whenever include/foo.h changes, however it doesn't do that when using the Makefile generator. It works if `foo.h` is in the same directory as `foo.cc`, or if `foo.cc` specifies the full relative path rather than relying on the include path.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It seems that your `src/foo.cc` **actually** includes some **other** `foo.h` header, not the one which you are trying to change. Note, that relative path in `target_include_directories` may work unexpectedly; it is better to use absolute paths there.

Comment: No, it refers to the exact foo.h file I'm expecting. The same project, where foo.h contains `#define LOL 10` and foo.cc prints the value of LOL in main, will print 10. Changing the number in foo.h will change the printed number.

Comment: What is your workflow? Are you doing a proper out of source build? Which platform are you on, and which version of CMake are you using? Can you list the steps that you take? Also, as the other commenter said, don't use a relative path (as you can read in the documentation). Instead use an absolute path (based on CMake variable like $CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this behavior is a bug introduced in CMake 3.15: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/19507

3.14.6 and earlier recompiles `src/foo.cc` when `include/foo.h` changes, as expected.